# Measuring on OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, distance, area

These days, I am trying to develop web map using openlayers. I copy source code from [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/measure.html)
Then I changed code to display my data.B ut it does not work, even map is also not showing. In chrome shows `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'containsLonLat' of null"`

Here is the full code. Please forgive me about amount of data. Really Thanks for your time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="3.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="4.css" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #controlToggle li {
        list-style: none;
    }
    p {
        width: 512px;
    }
    #options {
        position: relative;
        width: 512px;
    }
    #output {
        float: right;
    }

    /* avoid pink tiles */
    .olImageLoadError {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }
</style>
<script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, measureControls;
    function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {
    projection: 'EPSG:5235',
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(105097.88755998248, 181965.81596899,
    107146.57905998248, 183739.10926899),
    maxResolution: 156543.0339,
    units: 'm'
     });

        var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('OpenLayers                   WMS','http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sac/wms',{layers: 'sac:Luse'},{});

        map.addLayers(wmsLayer);
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());


        // style the sketch fancy
        var sketchSymbolizers = {
            "Point": {
                pointRadius: 4,
                graphicName: "square",
                fillColor: "white",
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWidth: 1,
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: "#333333"
            },
            "Line": {
                strokeWidth: 3,
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: "#666666",
                strokeDashstyle: "dash"
            },
            "Polygon": {
                strokeWidth: 2,
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: "#666666",
                fillColor: "white",
                fillOpacity: 0.3
            }
        };
        var style = new OpenLayers.Style();
        style.addRules([
            new OpenLayers.Rule({symbolizer: sketchSymbolizers})
        ]);
        var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({"default": style});

        // allow testing of specific renderers via "?renderer=Canvas", etc
        var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
        renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] :     OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;

        measureControls = {
            line: new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(
                OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
                    persist: true,
                    handlerOptions: {
                        layerOptions: {
                            renderers: renderer,
                            styleMap: styleMap
                        }
                    }
                }
            ),
            polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(
                OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {
                    persist: true,
                    handlerOptions: {
                        layerOptions: {
                            renderers: renderer,
                            styleMap: styleMap
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        };

        var control;
        for(var key in measureControls) {
            control = measureControls[key];
            control.events.on({
                "measure": handleMeasurements,
                "measurepartial": handleMeasurements
            });
            map.addControl(control);
        }

   map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(106017, 102881), 10);

        document.getElementById('noneToggle').checked = true;
    }

    function handleMeasurements(event) {
        var geometry = event.geometry;
        var units = event.units;
        var order = event.order;
        var measure = event.measure;
        var element = document.getElementById('output');
        var out = "";
        if(order == 1) {
            out += "measure: " + measure.toFixed(3) + " " + units;
        } else {
            out += "measure: " + measure.toFixed(3) + " " + units + "<sup>2</" + "sup>";
        }
        element.innerHTML = out;
    }

    function toggleControl(element) {
        for(key in measureControls) {
            var control = measureControls[key];
            if(element.value == key && element.checked) {
                control.activate();
            } else {
                control.deactivate();
            }
        }
    }

    function toggleGeodesic(element) {
        for(key in measureControls) {
            var control = measureControls[key];
            control.geodesic = element.checked;
        }
    }

    function toggleImmediate(element) {
        for(key in measureControls) {
            var control = measureControls[key];
            control.setImmediate(element.checked);
        }
    }


   </script>
   </head>
  <body onload="init()">
   <h1 id="title">OpenLayers Measure Example</h1>
   <div id="tags">
    measuring, geodesic, area, length, distance
   </div>
   <p id="shortdesc">
    Demonstrates the measure control to measure distances and areas.
   </p>
   <div id="map_element" class="smallmap"></div>
   <div id="options">
    <div id="output">
    </div>
    <ul id="controlToggle">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="none" id="noneToggle"
                   onclick="toggleControl(this);" checked="checked" />
            <label for="noneToggle">navigate</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="line" id="lineToggle"   onclick="toggleControl(this);" />
            <label for="lineToggle">measure distance</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="polygon" id="polygonToggle" onclick="toggleControl(this);" />
            <label for="polygonToggle">measure area</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="geodesic" id="geodesicToggle" onclick="toggleGeodesic(this);" />
            <label for="geodesicToggle">use geodesic measures</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="immediate" id="immediateToggle" onclick="toggleImmediate(this);" />
            <label for="immediateToggle">use immediate measures</label>
        </li>
       </ul>
       <p>Note </p>
       </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise,I am new to this forum and sorry for mistake.Now i am aware of it.

Comment: I couldn't find the problem, try to put some console outputs to identify the function that raises the error or debug the code in firefox or chrome. Ex. Before each function put a console.log('Before function x').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the reason for some reason I replace this line  `map.addLayers(wmsLayer);` using  this `map.addLayers([wmsLayer]);`. Now all works correctly.

I think to add one layer it is not must to use `[]` brackets.

Any idea?

Comment: map.addLayer() accepts a single layer, while map.addLayers() accepts an array of layers. The docs arent clear on the matter, but since the one is using the plural form (layers) it should be obvoius